# How to yield $f(c+) = f(c)$ from $f^{'}_{+}(c) \le \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, derivatives

I'm looking at a solution to one question, and part of it is: $f^{'}_{+}(c) \le \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$ ($c < x$, f is convex) is proved, then multiplying
this inequality by $(x − c)$ and letting $x → c+$ yield $f(c+) = f(c)$. I'm confused about how this result is yielded, thanks a lot for any help!

*Original part is in the solution to Q3.3.6 in Omar Hijab's Introduction to Calculus and Classical Analysis 4th edition

Comment: If $c$ is fixed then this is false. Perhaps it is assumed that $f^{'}_{+}(c) (x-c)\le {f(x)-f(c)}$ holds for all $c$ for all $x>c$.